# Manage cookies with cUrl

Tags: php

Hello i have a problem trying to store cookies in a txt file.
my_cookies.txt is a txt in the same folder of this file.

I want to manage cookie before and after login, in this example facebook
Then i want to insert that cookie in a database but first i need to put it in a .txt or atleast save

Obviously email and password dont be those. =)

```
<?php

/* STEP 2. define path of form_action */
$url = "https://facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
$email = "nn";
$password = "nn";

/* STEP 3. create a connection with curl, give post information and save cookies */
$handler = curl_init();
//insert in the handler the path
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//insert in the handler parameters of post
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($email).'&pass='.urlencode($password));

//insert in the handler option to allow sending post information
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST,1);

curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//load and save cookies generates in temp file
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");

//catch information
curl_setopt ($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//define agent
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0");

$response = curl_exec ($handler);

curl_close($handler);

echo $response; 
?>
```

Thanks for your help =) and i hope that you can do anything to help me :(

Answer (score 1):

facebook provide an API which is much less error prone than using curl to random facebook pages

To answer your actual question though  [this is the function you are looking for](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
it reads the file in to a variable which you can then store

Answer (score 1):

**PHP 5.3+**

```
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__."/my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__."/my_cookies.txt");
```

**PHP 5.2-**

```
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/my_cookies.txt");
```

**Also use absolute paths for files**. *`__DIR__` gives you that power!*

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

I've tryed with __DIR__ but the system doesnt save information in my txt file.

do you have something else in mind?? =)

Comment: What i need is save all cookies that some domain response me when i send a request

Comment: @GDedieu92 If you set the Cookie Jar/File path right, cURL will store the cookies for you. You can open the file and take a look. See if it contains what you expect it to.

Comment: # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.facebook.com TRUE / FALSE 1436735520 datr IHHgUZJgrtWC29_iu6sAFf-u
.facebook.com TRUE / FALSE 1 reg_ext_ref deleted
.facebook.com TRUE / FALSE 0 reg_fb_gate https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F
.facebook.com TRUE / FALSE 0 reg_fb_ref https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F

that's cookie.txt =) i could do it =).

that's like a system deny isnt? i mean those are not cookies

Comment: @GDedieu92 That's the cookie storage format and those are cookies. But if the login cookies are set by JS (JavaScript), you can't do this.

Comment: Thank you very much at everyone that help me =).

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can assign cookies to a `$cookies` variable and use that in place,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
```

and then after cookies' work is done in cURL process. you can do whatever you want to that variable(`$cookies`).

**TIP:**

1. For storing into .txt - you `__FILE__` to store same directory or append `__FILE__` with more path to store in another directory.
2. You can use `md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` for generating Separate use .txt
3. For storing into Database, `INSERT` command will be okay.